# how to sort elequent results in laravel when using eager loading

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to sort an elequent query on the basis of

> created_at

but nothing works 
my query

```
$newspaper_more_info = newspaper_jobad::with('sector', 'newspaper', 'province', 'test', 'catagory')->where('test_id', $job_test->id)->paginate(15)
```

i tried

```
 $newspaper_more_info = newspaper_jobad::with('sector', 'newspaper', 'province', 'test', 'catagory')->where('test_id', $job_test->id)->paginate(15)->sortBy('created_at');

$newspaper_more_info = newspaper_jobad::with('sector', 'newspaper', 'province', 'test', 'catagory')->where('test_id', $job_test->id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(15)
```

but not worked for.
and I also have a question is I am using eager loading or lazy loading I don't know I just implemented this but don't know the exact term

Comment: Are the results sorted if you don't paginate and just log the results of the query?.  the "with" call is eager loading that relationships data.

Comment: Model::with()->where(CONDITION)->orderBy()->paginate(N_ROWS); worked for me.

Comment: you are right but i want pagination too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a closure as a value in the `with` call to add constraints to the eager loaded SQL. [You can read about it here under the title "Constraining Eager Loads"](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

```
$newspaper_more_info = newspaper_jobad::with([
    'sector' => function($query) {
        $query->orderBy('created_at'); // This will sort the 'sector' relationship by the created_at column.
    }, 'newspaper', 'province', 'test', 'catagory'
    ])->where('test_id', $job_test->id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(15)
```